# How to find varation stock woocommerece

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to find a variation stocks text I have did with below code but i am looking any proper method. I get below given code from `templates/single-product/add-to-cart/variable.php` file from woocommerece  plugin. please any help will be appreciated.

```
        $terms = wc_get_product_terms( $product->id, $attribute, array( 'fields' => 'all' ) );

            foreach ( $terms as $term ) {

                if ( in_array( $term->slug, $options ) ) {
                    $product_variations_cus = $product->get_available_variations();  // my custom code start from here
                    foreach($product_variations_cus as $var_cus){
                        foreach($var_cus['attributes'] as $stock) {
                            if($term->slug==$stock)
                            $availability_html = $var_cus['availability_html']; // end here
                        }

                    }   

                    $html .= '<option value="' . esc_attr( $term->slug ) . '" ' . selected( sanitize_title( $args['selected'] ), $term->slug, false ) . '>' . esc_html( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_variation_option_name', $term->name ) ) .' '.$availability_html.'</option>';
                }
            }
```

Actually i want to add stock text to varation  dropdown  can see in image.[image]

Answer (score 2):

don't edit templates.
paste this in your theme's functions.php instead.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_variation_option_name', 'woocommerce_variation_option_name', 10 );
function woocommerce_variation_option_name( $name ) {
    global $product;

    foreach( $product->get_children() as $variation_id ) {
        $variation = wc_get_product( $variation_id );

        if ( in_array( strtolower( $name ), $variation->get_attributes() ) ) {
            $availability = $variation->get_availability();
            return $name . ' ' . $availability['availability'];
        }
    }

    return $name;
}
```

it will look something like this:
[image]

Comment: @Reigal not working. In image you can see i have print the name and  $variation->get_attributes() array? In_array is not satisfied i think?

Comment: well, the idea is there already... you should be able to fixed the code that relates to what you have...

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    global $product;
    $product_variations = $product->get_available_variations();

    foreach ($product_variations as $variation)  {
        $var_data = $variation['attributes'];
        $var_data['in_stock'] = $variation['is_in_stock'];
    }

?>
```

Check this out

Comment: THank you buddy. Yeah i know that but i want this code by term_id or term slug. Means i want to pass term_id then they stocks.

Comment: Please you can see in my code select option in last i have written in stock etc.